# How to redirect URL to Apache knox gateway(port is 8443) when visiting hadoop ui(port is 50070) or hbase ui (port is 16010))?

Tags: apache-knox

My web browser directly accesses the UI of the Namenode; after Apache knox is installed, when the host of the Namenode receives an http request to access port 50070, the request is to redirect  the UI of the Gateway and after authenticated user could access hdfsui through Apache KNOX,how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following docs links should provide some insights into how to configure the use of the JWTRedirectAuthenticationHandler for any of the Hadoop UIs. The use of this provider requires Kerberos/SPNEGO enabled on the http ports for the UIs and that this handler be configured for extending the typical kerberos support to also include the KnoxSSO JWT cookie.

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/installing-knox/content/set_up_knox_sso_for_components.html